# Get Request Content of PUT method in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, vcf-vcard

I am trying to fetch "PUT" request content which is VCard  via WCF.
here is its content,

```
PUT https://mysite.com/
Host: mysite.com
Content-Type: text/vcard; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 280
Accept-Language: en-us

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:test;Syeda;;;
FN:Syeda test
item1.EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=pref:test@hotmail.com
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:021 3123456
REV:2013-12-09T13:51:45Z
UID:318D8B19-BBC0-4841-A831-89E224C27A2D
END:VCARD
```

when i am trying to fetch it it is giving the following error,

```
Expecting element 'string' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Binary', namespace ''.
```

Is there any workaroung anybody knows to access VCard content.

Though, i am able to get those request's content that is in Xml format.

Thanks!

**Update:**

Previously, i was fetching the request content using this line of code.

```
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()
```

This work fine until the request is in xml format.But, when request is bringing content given above it returns word "Stream" as a string.

And, when i tried to do something like this,

```
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody<String>();
```

I am getting error shown above.

Comment: Should we *guess* your code?

Comment: You can't just fling a VCard at a service expecting SOAP. Please explain in detail what you are trying to do and why you ould expect it to work. At least show the code you use to "fetch", which apparently is giving an error.

Comment: It would be good to see all request body if it is possible.

Comment: @Tony: This is the whole request body that PUT request is giving.I am able to see the content length.But, Not able to get the content.